# Passing arguments/parameters to OnClickListener()

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I'm new to Android and I'm still trying to wrap my head around some of these concepts, so I'm sorry if I have to ask for frequent clarification.

I'm trying to override/create my own `OnClickListener`. However, I'm getting this error saying that `startActivity(Intent)` is undefined for my class...and I can't figure out why I'm getting this error.

```
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class ContactOCL implements OnClickListener {
    String contactInfo;
    public ContactOCL(String contactInfo) {
        this.contactInfo = contactInfo;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + contactInfo));
            startActivity(callIntent); // Error here
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
            Log.e("Calling a Phone Number", "Call failed", activityException);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your logcat errors.

Comment: Barney: It's a compile time error.

Comment: Is the intent/class declared in your manifest?

Comment: Nobody reads :( startActivity doesn't exist in a vanilla class like he has. He needs access to context in order to call that.

Comment: As @Simon André Forsberg said, it's an issue at compile time...so I can't really post a non-existent logcat/stack trace.

Comment: @BenBenard Whether or not the intent is declared in the manifest or not is a question for runtime, not compile time.

Comment: You can't start an activity from a non activity class.

Comment: @user2045570 Depends on what you mean by "from". I'd say that you can, by calling the method on the activity. Even though the code itself is in a non-activity class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you already have a `View` passed to `onClick()`, no need to also pass an Activity to the enclosing class. Just do:

```
v.getContext().startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: +1 Better solution than the one I had. I should say to myself: "Keep it simple, stupid"

Comment: Under normal circumstances, your way is the way to go :-)

Answer (score 5):

To start an activity, you need an activity.

One solution is to pass along your activity to your ContactOCL class

```
public ContactOCL(Activity activity, String contactInfo) {
    this.contactInfo = contactInfo;
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

Then to start the activity, you use

`activity.startActivity(callIntent);`

Then when you create this ContactOCL class, you do it by adding the activity parameter, something like: `new ContactOCL(this, contactInfo);` (I am assuming you create the ContactOCL from your activity class)

Edit: Although my solution works in the general case, for this special case it is not necessary to do it like this since you can access the activity from the view. Instead, see [solution suggested by A--C here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123498/passing-arguments-parameters-to-onclicklistener/15123601#15123601).

Answer (score 1):

This class would work as an inner class in an `Activity` - just drop it in and remove the `public` class modifier:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    class ContactOCL implements OnClickListener {
        String contactInfo;
        public ContactOCL(String contactInfo) {
            this.contactInfo = contactInfo;
        }

        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + contactInfo));
                startActivity(callIntent); // No Error here
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
                Log.e("Calling a Phone Number", "Call failed", activityException);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: +1. This is the way I usually do it. I tend to over-use inner classes sometimes :)