# Custom OnClickListener/OnClick for a TextView - cannot be found

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener

This is an extension of the (my) following questions:

- [NullPointerException with self-implemented OnClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124640/nullpointerexception-with-self-implemented-onclicklistener)
- [Passing arguments/parameters to OnClickListener()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123498/passing-arguments-parameters-to-onclicklistener)

That aside, I'm getting the following runtime error/crash when I click on my TextLabel:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onClick(View) in the activity class org.radio.app.Contacts for onClick handler on view class android.widget.TextView with id 'contactLabel'
```

I thought it was because I had my custom OnClickListener implementation in a different file. I tried putting it in my activity file itself, but I'm getting the same error.

And my XML for my TextView has the following:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/contactLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Label"
                android:textColor="@color/orange_theme_text"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:paddingRight="7dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

EDIT: Here's my custom OnClickListener, which even has an OnClick defined:

```
private class ContactOCL extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    String contactInfo;
    public ContactOCL(String contactInfo) {
        this.contactInfo = contactInfo;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.v("onClick", "Are we even getting here?");
        // Check if contactInfo is an email address or a phone number
        if (contactInfo.contains("@"))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri data = Uri.parse("mailto:" + contactInfo);
            intent.setData(data);
            startActivity(intent); 
        }

        // Otherwise we have a phone number
        else
        {
            try {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + contactInfo));
                v.getContext().startActivity(callIntent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
                Log.e("Calling a Phone Number", "Call failed", activityException);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT AGAIN: Here's a snippet of my activity:

```
TextLabel = (TextView) viewCI.findViewById(R.id.contactLabel);
TextLabel.setOnClickListener(new ContactOCL(info[i]));
```

Comment: Did you try adding listener in code?

Comment: Edited. The entire class you see above was even added to my activity and it didn't work.

Comment: i bet you need to get rid of the onClickListner interface...

Comment: @cbrulak I was thinking of this too, but the only problem I have is trying to implement calling/emailing from a ListView.

Comment: Oh? it from a listview? ie you click is coming from a list view element? then you need to do something way different...

Comment: I've had another idea in mind, but however an issue arises in the case where I have multiple contact options in a ListView (IE, both a phone number and an email).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up scrapping the overall TextView click and just doing an onClick for each ListView item, which works perfectly fine. It might cause problems in the future, but it'll have to do for now and I need to move onto working on other functionalities. :/

Answer (score 0):

did you declare the following in the code

```
public void onClick(View v){
    // ur code
}
```

EDIT:

when you write android:onClick in the layout xml you need not implement the onClickListener. And if you want to implement you custom onClickListener do the following

remove

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

add the following lines in your code.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactLabel);
tv.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: I did. I edited my question with the code for the custom OnClickListener/onClick as well.

Comment: The only reason why I had to implement my own onClickListener was because I had to pass in a variable (IE, a phone number or an email address) to it. I also have something similar in my code. Looks like I can't add it here, so it's been added to my first post/question.

Comment: use setOnClickListener to set the listener in your view

Comment: Edited question with my code snippet. I've been using setOnClickListener the whole time and it still won't work.

Comment: instead of using TextLabel.setOnClickListener(new ContactOCL(info[i])); use TextLabel.setOnClickListener(this) if you are calling this mehotd within the activity. dont know why your code is not running .. there might be any hidden mistake :S

Comment: No, the OP needs to call `new ContactOCL(info[i])` in the `setOnClickListener` because that is the custom class

Answer (score 0):

You need to take out

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

from your xml. It is looking for this method which doesn't exist in your `Activity` but in your custom `onClickListener` class. If you delete that line then it should work for you, or at least fix that error

Try changing this

```
TextLabel.setOnClickListener(new ContactOCL(info[i]));
```

to this

```
TextLabel.setOnClickListener(new ContactOCL(info[i]), this); //this referring to `Activity` context
```

then change your `onClick` class constructor to accept `context`

**Edit**

Since this is an `onClickListener` class now and not being called from the xml, you need Override the method in your custom class

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
...
}
```

**Another Option**

Its fine but there is just something we are missing and its hard to say without seeing everything involved. However, if you only create the custom listener class to have access to the variable that you pass from your `Activity` then you really don't need the class. You already have the variable `info[]`. Make sure that is declared as a member variable of your `Activity` class then you can implement the `onClick` in the xml

In xml put this back in

```
<TextView
...
android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

Then in your `Activity` class

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
      // do your work here. You have access to the contact because it was initialized as a member variable
}

 public class YourActivity extends Activity
{
DataType info[] = new DataType();

 public void onCreate()
{
    //set your contentView, button, etc here
}
```

Comment: It does, but the only issue now is that nothing happens when I click on my TextView. :(

Comment: Do you mean `new ContactOCL(info[i], this));`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It needs the activity context

Comment: Still doesn't work, unfortunately. From what I can see in my LogCat, it looks like my onClick method in my implemented OCL is even being called.

Comment: Put a break point inside your `onClick` method to be sure it isn't getting there. Are you getting any new errors in logcat?

Comment: Oh, you need to override the method. Add this
@Override above the method declaration in your custom class

Comment: When debugging and reaching a breakpoint, the info should go into the Console tab, correct? If that's the case, nothing is happening so it's not getting to `onClick`.

Comment: `@Override` should go at the top of the class, or at the top of `onClick`? I'm assuming it's the latter, but I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Putting `@Override` at the top of my onClick function gave me a compiler error: `The method onClick(View) of type Contacts.ContactOCL must override a superclass method`

Comment: When you hover over the error does it offer to implement the method? If so, let it then put your code into the generated method

Comment: The only solution it offers is to remove the `@Override` annotation, unfortunately.

Comment: Nevermind, I resolved it because my Java compiler for my project specifically wasn't set to 1.6+. I included the line in my XML though and I'm still getting the error unfortunately...

Comment: Yes, because you aren't supposed to have that in your xml if you are using a listener. Take that line back out. That tells it to look in the class with the view for that function. Also, I'm not sure if you need to extend `Activity` in your listener class. You shouldn't need to

Comment: Took it out, and nothing is happening still--even with a breakpoint added in. Not sure about the extension of `Activity` though...

Comment: And you put the @Override annotation back in, correct? You shouldn't need to extend `Activity` because you pass in the `context` in that parameter

Comment: Correct. :( This is making me wonder if the way I'm implementing the general functionality is...Java/Android-friendly or even "correct".

Comment: I edited my answer with a simpler solution. I'm really tired so may have missed something but that should make your life a little easier

Comment: So `info[]` is defined as a private String[] in my code. I guess I'm just confused on how to access a specific element of the array and how to actually use that specific element. I was thinking of doing a switch/case with the `contactLabel` ID, but it looks like all of the IDs are the same. This was probably my first thought of a workaround, but the issue that I've stated is what's just throwing me off.

Comment: That's a separate issue. I don't mind helping more but this post is getting cluttered and I don't see the `info[]` variable. If we fixed your `onClick()` issue then you may kindly accept and open a new question with the relevant code to your `info[]` question. It will be much easier to sort through without all of this other nonrelated stuff.

Comment: I answered my question, but I haven't been able to accept it and won't be able to for at least a few more hours. Sorry for the spam.

Comment: No worries. I was just letting you know that it gets confusing if we look at too many issues in one post. As I said, I will be happy to help in another post that is focused on that issue with only relevant code. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need not have to make your Activity implement an onClickListener when you have defined the function name in android:onClick attribute of the TextView in your xml. You can do either the xml definition or through OnClickListener interface.

***XML Definition***

When you define

```
     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contactLabel"
            ....
            ....
            android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

you are saying when the TextView is clicked it should look for a function named "onClick" in my activity where my TextView is defined. For this reason, **the name of your function here could be ANYTHING (not necessarily onClick)**.
You now just have to make sure that a function with same name is there in your activity. Syntax is:

```
    public void <function name> (View v)
```

---

***OnClickListener implementation***

Another way to get your Activity handle the clicking of your TextView is doing it programatically, not through xml
This is done when your Activity implements an OnClickListener and overrides the following method:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
```

**Note that the function name has to be onClick in this case and the function should be an override function**

For this you have to now tell that the Activity is handling the clicks for your TextView. You do that by

```
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactLabel);
    textView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

---

Finally, since you were doing both and the function name for your function happen to be same as an already existing function inside the OnClickListener class which is implemented by your Activity, there is an ambiguity and hence the exception is thrown.

Comment: So for the XML implementation, I just have to include the function in the activity itself, right? Is it also possible to pass an additional variable to the custom-made function as well? (Probably a dumb question, but I'd just like to be sure)

Comment: Not a dumb question but no, it only accepts the view that was clicked

Comment: Shoot. That might be a problem then.

Comment: As @codeMagic mentioned, you cannot pass additional variables as function argument, but you can setTag() to your view and gettag() in the onClick(View v) function to determine which view was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

So, if this is a listview  you need to have add a method call to your Adapter, let's just assume it is an array adapter, called `arrayAdapter`

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
  //do some magic to create the new view

  View v = new View(....)// or assign convertView

  v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListner....)
}
```

Comment: It's kind of a ListView, but I've got a bunch of TextViews inside of the ListView, and I'm trying to make a specific TextView clickable. I'm going to have to look at this implementation as a last resort.